# time data "45139" doesn't match format "%d-%m-%Y" error

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime

How do i correct error "time data "45139" doesn't match format "%d-%m-%Y". the date column to be read from excel file is in format "01-08-2023"; the date column type shows as 'int64' after reading in Pandas dataframe.

Also have tried below code to convert to date but getting above error

```
df_sales['Day']=df_sales['Day'].apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(str(x),format='%d-%m-%Y'))
```